# Meaning of 参考に in this sentence

Tags: translation, meaning

[image]

> 普通のカマは細部を見るときの参考にしています

How I can guess it's meaning:

> When you look at the details of ordinary sickle, use it as a reference

But I'm not sure due 参考する in this sentence. How it will be more correctly?

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what this sentence means. Can you provide some more context where it is used? 参考にする means "to use a a reference", but it's hard to translate this sentence without context.

Comment: Please, wait a second!

Answer (score 2):

It seems it is talking of some wooden sickle to be used in some matsuri like 地鎮祭{じちんさい}.

I am not 100% sure (there is not even much context) but I think the sentence you are discussing can be translated simply as: *a standard/regular (that is, a real) sickle is used as reference when looking at the details.*

I guess the point is that the wooden one is made precisely to look like a real one except that it is entirely made in wood and hence safe (which it is also explained in the sentence above: [...]すべて木でできているのでさわっても安心です.

Comment: My pleasure. :)